# Trying to make UIAlertController, can't seem to initialize

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

I'm making a simple game of hangman for a class, and I'm trying to show a UIAlert when the user has won/lost the game. I've tried following the UIAlertController initialization exactly as outlined here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller

I've tried doing exactly what they do (and even copy pasted their example code into my method to see if it would work, but I got the same error):

```
let winAlert = UIAlertController(title: "You won!", message: "Go bears!", preferredStyle: .alert)
```

which gets me an error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". What can I do?

### Edit

Fixed typo in post.

Also, if I try changing the last field preferredStyle from `.alert` to `UIAlertController.Style.alert` I get the error warning: "UIAlertController has no member Style" even though the documentation states that it has an enum named Style?

Answer (score 1):

You have written ***UIControllerAlert***. Try ***UIAlertController*** instead. Also don't forget to import UIKit.

```
let winAlert = UIAlertController(title: "You won!", message: "Go bears!", preferredStyle: .alert)
```

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer, but I just mistyped on this post! My code has UIAlertController, but is still having the problem.

Comment: Are you importing UIKit? Maybe this solves the issue

Comment: Yep, it's imported.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. I was working collaboratively with someone, and I didn't realize that they had created a file named UIAlertController that was hiding/overloading "UIAlertController" somehow.